# Is there any third-party framework or technology to reload an updated(latest) jar dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic

As title, I have a requirement to load the latest jar if the jar have been updated while the application is on running mode. Due to the fact that the jar status is unstable , it will be changed at any time. So guys, could you give me sort of suggestion about this? Appreciate.

The reason why jar file becomes unstable is that this project is under the programming and debugging status. And this jar need to feed for another running java application.Thus the interface might be specfied but the implements are supposed to have an efficient modification. If we can dynamically reload updated jar, we can speed up the debug time.

Comment: You might be able to do something like this with OSGi; but to be honest I don't know for sure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi

Comment: How come the jar status is unstable? Is someone programming and uploading all the time, while people are running the applet? Could you solve it by reloading *data* instead of *code*?

Comment: @The Nail Please see the edited reply. Yeah, coding might be an option . Do we have sort of better strategy?

Comment: Duplicate, e.x. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728140/can-i-dynamically-unload-and-reload-other-versions-of-the-same-jar