# when is a class is unloaded

Tags: java, classloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    }
```

As per my knowledge a class is loaded by classLoader in JVM when it requires that particlar class .
But you please tell me when a class is exactly unloaded ??

Comment: Also See [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.7)

Comment: Do you mean the class definition or any instance of that class?

Comment: @JigarJoshi JLS link is invalid. Could you give me the updated link?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7

Answer (score 3):

Classes are eligible to be unloaded if the class loader is GC'ed.  So in your example, there are no more references to `MyClassLoader`.