# When  does a class unload from heap memory

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)

When does a class unload from memory?

For loading a class we can call `Class.forName("NameOfClass");` or when we create an object of a class, then the class loaded into memory.

Comment: Was about to answer, but the first link on google was this question on SO: [Unloading classes in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)

Comment: Why do you need that? Btw, that is dependent on the JVM and might not be done at all (see the infamous PermGen problem)

Answer (score 3):

**Classes**

Classes will be loaded by a *classloader* and will (may) be unloaded when that classloader is garbage collected. In *normal* applications, where we don't care about classloaders: classes will never be unloaded.

**Instances of classes / objects**

Objects will be created on the heap and *deleted* when the garbage collector detects, that there is no reference to that instance/object anymore.

(Just in short, better details: see question [Unloading classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java))

Comment: Do the Java classes provided by JDK (e.g. `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.math.BigIntege`r) get unloaded at all?

Answer (score 1):

In simple words :

Class gets unloaded when all the references to the class(and their instances) are removed and the classloader used is garbage collected.

Comment: No, it _might_ then be elligible for garbage collection but in some cases the class might actually never be collected.

Comment: Not correct. A class will (may) be unloaded only if it's classloader gets garbage collected. You're answering *objects/instances*.

Comment: Agree , references to the class and to the classloader itself should be removed .

Comment: @CodeBuzz - there are *no* (Java-)references to the class. The *class* is a jvm internal datastructure, based on the class file. I have the feeling ,that you still mix up classes and instances...

Comment: As per my knowledge when an class loaded in to memory an instance of class Class is created and which content the information about the loaded class. we can get the instance of class Class by writing ClassName.class.
So to unload a class from memory , that instance of class Class should be collected by garbage collector.

But here is the main point, when the garbage collector destroy the Object of class Class(created due to loading of class)
generally an object is eligible for garbage collector , if it's lost all his reference.
so when and how the object of class Class lost his all references

Answer (score 0):

When exactly a class will be unloaded is not defined, just as when exactly an object may be garbage collected is not defined. What *is* defined is when it *can* be unloaded:

> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class
>   loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector