# Where are all my applet classes - Creating a custom ClassLoader

Tags: java, class, loader

I am trying to build a custom FileClassLoader because I need to unload a dll at a certain point in my application.   I instantiate the class loader has follows:

```
 public class FileClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

  private Map<String, Class<?>> classes;

  public FileClassLoader() {
      super(FileClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
      classes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
   }
  .......
```

}

But when I check the size of the classes HashMap it is zero.    The classes are packaged in a jar, and the application (which runs fine) is an applet.   Prior to trying to add this custom class loader, the application was working properly so what am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: If you don't put things in that HashMap, nothing else will.

Comment: By "dll", I assume you actually mean "jar", correct?

Comment: We need the code where you're actually loading the classes, as that's where you'll need to be adding classes to the HashMap.  The constructor doesn't really tell us much about how the classloader is working...

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java.