# Most efficient way to execute method from jar that is stored in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, jar

What is the best way to execute a method stored in a jar, with the jar in the form or a byte array. I don't want to however write the bytes to a file or a temp file, I just want to run it from the byte array itself (if it is possible)

Comment: Possibly related: [Loading a JAR dynamically from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28964450)

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212086/how-to-convert-a-bytearray-to-jar

Comment: @Pshemo with a bit of change i was able to execute using the second answer thanks