# When static variables memory will release in java?

Tags: java, oop, static, jvm, java-memory-model

I know nonstatic variables are released when variables are in out of scope, but scope for static variables are in all context.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134686/static-variables-what-is-their-life-span) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8704858/364056).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the garbage collector work on static variables or methods in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126833/does-the-garbage-collector-work-on-static-variables-or-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variable's memory is allocated at the start of the program, in regular memory, instead of the stack (memory set aside specifically for the program). 
    The advantage of this is that it makes your variable or procedure totally constant, and you can't accidentally change the value. the disadvantage of this is that the memory is not deallocated until the program is terminated. I have never heard anything that static values take any more memory than if they are declared regularly, but thier memory use is constant through.

Answer (score 2):

Since static classes/members loads once per class loader, when the class loader is eligible for GC, the static members also eligible for GC.

Comment: For simple programs, the default class loader is not unloaded, but in complex programs with multiple class loaders this does happen. +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey inshort, *if we configure/have multiple class loaders* :)

Comment: Thanks. Is it ok to say static members are alway in context?

Comment: `context` you mean `scope`?  Yes.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I mean static members are always in memory while application is running.

Comment: @totaloverdose Yes. You can say that.

Comment: @totaloverdose while the class loader is still be used, which for a simple program is the life of the application.