# Which better R.string.mystring or public static final String myString

Tags: java, android, performance

I would like to know the difference between

```
R.string.mystring
```

and

```
public static final String myString
```

in Android.

Which is better performance wise and why?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308623/xml-string-resources-vs-java-constant-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.string.mystring` --> can be converted to other languages (based on user's locale) LOCALIZATION

`public static final String myString` --> stays in one language.