# How to get a list of all classes that are loaded by the bootstrap class loader?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to figure out how to unload classes.

[Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)

However, I wish to be able to figure out what classes are already loaded. How can this be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the method getInitiatedClasses:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Comment: Hi Andres... How would I be able to get n instance of the Instrumentation object? I need to do it after jVM startup but not sure how this can be done

Comment: Watch this: http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/determining-what-classes-are-loaded-by.html

Answer (score 1):

Only as an alternative to Andres answer you can turn on `-verbose:class` and redirect stdout to a file. There we'll get this log

```
...
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
...
```

We can extract a class name, load it

```
Class cls = Class.forName(className);
```

if `cls.getClassLoader()` returns `null` it was loaded with bootstrap class loader.