# Java removing class from arraylist

Tags: java, class, memory, arraylist

If I have an Array List with classes in it and I remove a class from the list, will the class be removed/deleted and the memory it used be freed up?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you have *objects* in the `ArrayList`, not *classes*.

*Objects* are instances of *classes*, for example `Integer` is a *class*, when you do `Integer a = new Integer(1)`, then `a` is an object of the *class* `Integer`).

Java is [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), it means that you don't have to explicitly tell the compiler when to free the memory (like in C for example), the garbage collector will periodically check if the instance is not referenced anywhere else, and if that's the case, it means that the object can no longer be accessed and the memory will be freed.

What you can do is to call [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()) to tell the garbage collector that you want it to perform a collection. This is only an hint, there is no way to force an immediate collection.

Comment: I think he has an `ArrayList` of `Class` objects.

Answer (score 0):

No. You remove reference, not actual class.

Comment: what can i do to free up the memory it is using?

Comment: @user3866695 Nothing, just let the garbage collector do its thing.  You don't need manual memory management in Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java

Comment: thanks azurefrog and Arvy