# Java - Unloading classes

Tags: java

I'm loading classes with the standard Java classloader:

```
ClassLoader loader = new MemoryClassLoader(s.toByteArray());
Class<?> myClass = loader.loadClass(className);
```

MemoryClassLoader is directly derived from ClassLoader and overrides the findClass()-method:

```
Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
   return defineClass(name, byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
}
```

What I would like to know is if it is needed to unload the loaded class somehow. Is there any unload()-method or something I've to call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java

Comment: tl;dr `Class`es are garbage collected at the same time as their `ClassLoader`. You'll need more `ClassLoader` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to unload or unallocate your classes. The Garbage Collector (aka GC) does all the unset stuffs for you.

You can find information about GC here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29