# How to execute a static block for multiple times in java

Tags: java, static-block

I have given a task to execute static block for every 20 seconds. I have a class that consists of a static block.

```
public class Hello{
      static{
        System.out.println("helloo...");
      }
}
```

I know that static block executes when the class is loaded.

But i want to know is there any way to execute the static block for multiple times and how?

Comment: static block get executed when class is loaded, if you want multiple times use method

Comment: They question is, why do you want to do this?  Static blocks cannot do this.  How about adding the code as a static method and running the method as many times as needed?

Comment: You can't, unless your class is loaded by multiple classloaders. It will be executed once per classloader, when either an instance of `Hello` is initialized or a static method of `Hello` is invoked.

Comment: I have clearly addressed my problem here that i have to specifically do like this yet this question has 6 downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a Static Block can be Achieved by using Custom Class Loader.

**ClassReload.java**

```
    Class<?> load = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.Hello");
//Assume Hello class is in "com" package 
        load.newInstance().toString();
        URL[] urls = { load.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() };
        ClassLoader delegateParent = load.getClassLoader().getParent();
        try (URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, delegateParent)) {
            Class<?> reloaded = cl.loadClass(load.getName());
            reloaded.newInstance().toString();              
            }
            }
        }
```

[Refer Oracle Document for URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

Answer (score 0):

Static block runs when class loads, You can't run it multiple time.

Comment: what if i unload and load it again?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java

Comment: Actually, i found the solution with urlclassloader. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like any other block of code that you want to execute several times you can use a loop or better to create a static function and call it several times:

```
public class Hello{
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("helloo...");
    }

    public void someMethod() {

        for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
            hello();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. It will be run only once, when class is loads. There is one more chance you can write any number of static block in a class.

[https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/][1]