# Why Java Classloader does not release jars

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I need to load classes from jars, to do it I'm using:

`cls = Class.forName(className, false, classLoader);`

At the end, I want to delete these jars, but it seems that this is not possible because ClassLoader does not release the jars. So I used:

`classLoader.release();`

`System.gc();`

But unfortunately this does not solve the problem...

Comment: Release JARs.  It's not done.

Comment: How could I release JARs

Comment: You cannot. You should not.

Comment: @khouloud What's your use case? Why are you trying to release your JARs from memory?

Comment: @entpnerd I'm working with a custom classloader extending from ClassLoader. I'm trying to release jars, so I can delete these jars.

Comment: Ok, so why are you writing a custom class loader that can release JARs?

Comment: FYI I'm trying to drilldown on the business case to try to determine whether some workaround can be done.

Comment: There is no `release()` method in the `ClassLoader` API.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7), classes (and therefore JAR-files) cannot be unloaded explicitly.

It might be possible to achieve something similar with some trickery as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java), but it depends on the actual implementation of the JVM and is therefore nothing you should build on.