# Can I delete a class that has already been loaded in Java?

Tags: jvm

I have a request to assemble code strings and dynamically load them into the class, but the request may frequently modify the content of the class. Currently, I create a new class every time I make changes, but the old class will always be loaded into memory, and I am afraid of memory overflow

Ability to delete unused classes or dynamically modify class structures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java